# Erro ao importar JDOM

Tags: java

Galera,

Estou seguindo um tutorial para aprender sobre uma Calculadora Java feita de forma distribuída.

Porém, estou tendo um erro de importação da biblioteca JDOM, já importei de toda forma:
- Zipado
- Arquivo por arquivo
- Só o arquivo principal

Porém o erro persiste:

```
error: package org.jdom does not exist import org.jdom.Document;
```

[image: Imagem contendo os erros]

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Abraços,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para o pacote `org.jdom` você precisará de uma versão mais antiga do `JDOM`. Veja na imagem abaixo que para a versão `2.0.6` não há o pacote `org.jdom`, mas `org.jdom2`:

[image: Pacote na versão 2.0.6]

A versão `1.1.3` foi a mais recente que encontrei que possui o pacote `org.jdom`. Segue imagem da versão `1.1.3`:

[image: Pacote na versão 1.1.3]

Com o uso da versão `1.1.3`, caso apareçam outros erros, como [`NoClassDefFoundError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html) e [`LinkageError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/LinkageError.html), você deverá testar com versões inferiores a `1.1.3`.

Você pode fazer download da versão `1.1.3` neste link: [download](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jdom/jdom/1.1.3).

Outra solução é alterar os `import`s nas suas classes de `org.jdom` para `org.jdom2`, caso queira utilizar a versão mais recente da biblioteca.

Comment: Deu certo mano, muito obrigado.
No caso, usei como você informou: org.jdom2

Abraços!